# Laravel - check if aria-selected = true

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

in total I have 3 files which contain the following functionality:

1. I got a navigation bar which toggles 3 different areas.
2. I got a table which contains data
3. A file which include file 1 and 2 (master file)

So now if I open the master file I can go through all 3 areas but every are should contain different data in the table.
File 1

```
<div class="manage-budget-nav-wrapper text-left mx-lg mx-sm-4 mx-2">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs border-0" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link px-0 mr-sm-5 mr-3 ml-0 active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home-1" role="tab"
            aria-controls="home-1" aria-selected="true">Offenes Gesamtguthaben</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link px-0 mr-sm-5 mr-3 ml-0" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile-1" role="tab"
            aria-controls="profile-1" aria-selected="false">Spenden</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link px-0 mr-sm-5 mr-3 ml-0" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#redeem-1" role="tab"
            aria-controls="redeem-1" aria-selected="false">Gutschein</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <hr class="mt-0">
</div>
```

file 2

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover mb-4">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            @if (\Request::is('admin/locals/donations'))
                <th scope="col">Erwerbsdatum</th>
            @elseif (\Request::is('admin/locals/dashboard'))
                <th scope="col">Buchungstag</th>
            @endif
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {{-- @foreach transaction --}}
        @if (\Request::is('admin/locals/donations') class_exist)
            <tr>
                {{-- date of acquisition in d.m.Y --}}
                <td>{24.12.2020}</td>
            </tr>
        @elseif (\Request::is('admin/locals/dashboard'))
            <tr>
                {{-- booking day in d.m.Y --}}
                <td>{24.12.2020}</td>
            </tr>
        @endif
            {{-- @endforeach transaction --}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I already got some if statement but how can I check if e.g. area one is active or got class active. Inside the navigation to check `@if (aria-selected="true")`.

Comment: I'm really confused to see your code. Can you please provide the controller code?

Answer (score 0):

> how can I check if e.g. area one is active or got class active.
>
> Inside the navigation to check `@if (aria-selected="true")`

I think you misunderstood the purpose of Blade Engine. Blade files, alongside their directives are parsed by the PHP on server, not by the browser. Therefore you can't check a HTML attribute, or select them using Blade the way you do with javascript.

The question which rise is: why do you want to check if `aria-selected` is true? If it is to insert another tag, you should do that in javascript/[jQuery](https://jquery.com) (which again -- is a different layer than Blade):

```
$('div [aria-selected="true"]').map(function(element){
    $(element).append('<p>html code</p>')
})
```

- Blade directives = server
- Javascript = browser

Comment: okay but my question, is there a way how I can check if aria-selected == true like how you check if (\Request::is('/test/page1'))